# What is the point of computing for $dy$?

Tags: calculus, differential

I can understand the significance of computing for a derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ because you can see the slope (change in y in relation to the change in x) at any given point of a function.

By that logic, computing for $dy$ can find the change in the y axis at a given point x? What is the point of this?

Comment: How are you defining $dy$? The symbol $\frac{dy}{dx}$ does not generally mean '$dy$ divided by $dx$.'

Comment: I thought $d$ stood for delta? So delta y in relation to delta x?

Comment: You can compute $dy$ only when you know what it is, and in this case you will have your reasons to compute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I find taking the differential instead of the derivative makes it easier to keep my options open, and also makes it more amenable to multivariable equations.

For instance, say you have the equation $y^2 = e^x + z$.  If you take the differential, you get $2y\,dy = e^x\,dx + dz$.  From here, you can solve for the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if you like.  Or, you can divide both sides by $dt$ and get related rates.  You can set one of the differentials to zero to get partial differentials, etc.

Anyway, there's nothing wrong with the derivative, but, to me, it seems that *always* forcing it into a form of a derivative is messy.

Additionally, there are a *few* places where the derivative is misleading.  Take the equation $x = 0$.  The derivative with respect to $x$ would lead you to say $1 = 0$, but the differential is more clear: $dx = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In calculus, we generally define $\frac{d}{dx}$ as an operator that acts on a function $y$, meaning that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is just the output of an operator and the top and bottom are not independently defined. Throughout history many people have had the same urge as you to defined "dy" and "dx" independently, which leads to a field known as [infinitesimal calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal).

When Newton was first creating calculus, he originally thought of dy and dx as infinitesimals as well, and the math was only formalized with operators later.

Comment: It really depends, some undergraduate textbooks define $dy$ to mean $f'(x)\,\Delta x$, which is why I asked for clarification of definition.

Comment: @DMcMor I've heard people define $\Delta y=f'(x)\Delta x$, but I've never seen $dy=f'(x)\Delta x$. There is the implicit assumption of a variable $N$ in the notation $\Delta x$, whereas $dy$ should not be dependent on $N$.

Comment: I agree, and I'm not saying it's good notation, but it is something I've seen in business calculus textbooks.

Comment: @DMcMor Thank you for bringing this to my attention. If you recommend I change my answer, I will be sure to do so.